# error while running mongodb php program

Tags: php, mongodb

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mongo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212+lfs/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>       PHP Fatal error:  Class 'MongoClient' not found in /var/www/exhange/b1_functions.php on line 8

This is the error popped up when running a monogdb php program in ubuntu. How can I fix that?

Comment: did add `extension=mongo.so` to your `php.init` file?

Comment: yes i did it, i added the extension in /etc/php5/cli.php.ini and also /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini